# How to detect caller of a method and it's properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, methods

I want a method to detect method caller and properties.

**for example if I called that method on a button named 'btn', it should print "btn" in a message box for me.**

Searched around the web, but just found how to detect if the method has been called before!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you are looking for a generic approach that covers not only events but also other methods use the [Caller Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540(v=vs.110).aspx) feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `sender` object parameter. Something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    method1(sender);
}

public void method1(object sender)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        var caller = button.Name;
        MessageBox.Show(caller);//It shows button1
    }
}
```

Comment: or, if your compiler version is new enough, `if (sender is Button button)`